# How do I create a histogram by iterating over an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, histogram

So I was told to rewrite this question and outline my goal. They asked me to iterate over the array and "Use .each to iterate over frequencies and print each word and its frequency to the console... put a single space between the word and its frequency for readability."

```
puts "Type something profound please"
text = gets.chomp
words = text.split

frequencies = Hash.new 0
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by {|x,y| y}
words.each {|word| frequencies[word] += 1}
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by{|x,y| y}.reverse
puts word +" " + frequencies.to_s
frequencies.each do |word, frequencies|   

end
```

Why can't it convert the string into an integer? What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as below :

```
puts "Type something profound please"
text = gets.chomp.split
```

I called here [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) method.

```
hash = text.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word,freq_hsh|
  freq_hsh[word] += 1
end
```

I called below [`Hash#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) method.

```
hash.each do |word,freq|
  puts "#{word} has a freuency count #{freq}"
end
```

Now run the code :

```
(arup~>Ruby)$ ruby so.rb
Type something profound please
foo bar foo biz bar baz
foo has a freuency count 2
bar has a freuency count 2
biz has a freuency count 1
baz has a freuency count 1
(arup~>Ruby)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
puts "Type something profound please"
words = gets.chomp.split #No need for the test variable

frequencies = Hash.new 0
words.each {|word| frequencies[word] += 1}
words.uniq.each {|word| puts "#{word} #{frequencies[word]}"} 
#Iterate over the words, and print each one with it's frequency.
```

Comment: why `reverse` and `sort_by` need ? :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Linuxios. This worked. I'll have to go back and look at what I did wrong. We haven't learned about the .uniq method yet, but it looks like that's what made the difference, so I'll look it up so that I can utilize it on my own in the future

Comment: @user3324987: Sure. The problem in your original code was that you needed your puts in your loop, and you didn't need all that sorting. `uniq` is very simple, it just returns the array without any duplicates. So, `["hi", "hi", "the"]` becomes `["hi", "the"]`.

Answer (score 0):

*chunk* is a good method for this. It returns an array of 2-element arrays. The first of each is the return value of the block, the second is the array of original elements for which the block returned that value:

```
words = File.open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r:iso-8859-1").readlines
p words.chunk{|w| w[0].downcase}.map{|c, words| [c, words.size]}
=> [["a", 17096], ["b", 11070], ["c", 19901], ["d", 10896], ["e", 8736], ["f", 6860], ["g", 6861], ["h", 9027], ["i", 8799], ["j", 1642], ["k", 2281], ["l", 6284], ["m", 12616], ["n", 6780], ["o", 7849], ["p", 24461], ["q", 1152], ["r", 9671], ["s", 25162], ["t", 12966], ["u", 16387], ["v", 3440], ["w", 3944], ["x", 385], ["y", 671], ["z", 949]]
```